# Open high resolution images with Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I can't open a 24MP pictures on Python with opencv. It only opens the upper left part apparently and not the full image[image]. The kernel also stops after running the code.

Here's my code:
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

```
PICTURE_PATH_NAME = "IMG.JPG"
img = cv2.imread(PICTURE_PATH_NAME)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("Gray Image", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: *"The kernel"*? Which kernel?

Comment: As you already have a large image, it seems *"sub-optimal"* to unnecessarily open it as colour, thus requiring 3x the storage, and then generate a greyscale copy of it at the same time, for 4x the necessary storage. Why not just open it in greyscale if that's what you want? `im = cv2.imread(PATH,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

Comment: It doesn't work either

Comment: Try printing the shape of the image after loading it `print(img.shape)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for imshow as to how to get it to scale your image to fit the window at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563

> "If you need to show an image that is bigger than the screen
>   resolution, you will need to call `namedWindow("", WINDOW_NORMAL)`
>   before the imshow."