# cv2.imshow command doesn't work propley . Shows incomplete image

Tags: python, opencv

I am able to open the image but my image is not completely visible in the window . I mean it shows me cropped version of the image im using. It would be great if you can help me visualize the complete image shown through cv2.imshow().I am using the visual studio and below is the code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

Org_img=cv2.imread('coins.png',1)
img=cv2.imread('coins.png',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.imshow('image2',Org_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try checking the dimensions of your image with `print(img.shape)` - maybe it is too large.

Comment: See Fred's answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61825488/2836621

Comment: Thanks Guys I used namedWindow("", WINDOW_NORMAL) and it worked. Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The image is probably larger than the screen, use the resize function to adjust for the desired output, also take a look on the shape for checking these values and window flags in the second link.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('messi5.jpg')
res = cv.resize(img,None,fx=factor, fy=factor, interpolation = cv.INTER_CUBIC)
```

If factor > 1.0 the image is getting larger than the original and if factor < 1.0 you are reducing the image (factor = 0.5 will divide by 2), fx and fy can be different values.

[See geometric transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html)

[Window flags](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ggabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3acf621ace7a54954cbac01df27e47228f)